# How to read a file during simulation in Specman

Tags: specman

I need to read a file with input parameters for my test. However I dont want to hardcode the name of the file into the code.
How can I specify the name of the file from the command line for compiled e code?
Is there another way to do it for loaded e code? Why wont this work for compiled code?

Answer (score 1):

The generic solution would be to use the new sn_plus mechanism.
From command line add something like +my_file=filename

From your code you can access the argument with special functions sn_plusargs_exist to check if there is such argument, and read its value with sn_plus_value.

Another solution is passing filename as define from the command line, with -c flag, and inside your code read the file named with that define.

However, it doesn't work with compiled e code, since the defines are already calculated at compiling time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sn_plusargs_value() and sn_plusargs_exist() in your code.
Now you can pass your arguments file via command line with no need to re-compile your e code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can set an environment variable and retrieve its value in the e-code using

```
var filename := get_symbol("<VAR>")
```